# Ruby on Rails - How to delete entire parent json element if nested child has a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

Let's say I have this example JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
},
{
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Raised",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1005", "type": "DeleteMe" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }
        ]
},
{
    "id": "0003",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Old Fashioned",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" }
        ]
}
]
```

How would I delete the entire element that has a batter type with "DeleteMe"?  So basically, I want the entire element 0002 removed. I basically want to filter out all elements with batter type = "DeleteMe" in them.

Comment: Step 1) Parse the JSON. Step 2) Ask about the Ruby data structure instead. Step 3) Generate JSON from the updated data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json = '[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
      {
        "batter":
          [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
          ]
      },
    "topping":
      [
        { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
      ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Raised",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
      {
        "batter":
          [
            { "id": "1005", "type": "DeleteMe" }
          ]
      },
    "topping":
      [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }
      ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0003",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Old Fashioned",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
      {
        "batter":
          [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
          ]
      },
    "topping":
      [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" }
      ]
  }
]'


parsed_data = JSON.parse(json)
result = parsed_data.delete_if do |data|
  data['batters']['batter'].detect { |batter| batter['type'] == 'DeleteMe' }
end
```

You can try `result.to_json` if you want your output as json.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
JSON.parse(json).delete_if do |sweet| 
  sweet['batters']['batter'].detect { |batter| batter['type'] == 'DeleteMe' } 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `json` be your JSON data structure.

```
require 'json'

arr = JSON.parse(json).
           reject { |h| h['batters']['batter'].any? { |g| g['type'] == "DeleteMe" } }
```

One can then execute `arr.to_json` to obtain the revised JSON object, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
json = 
'[
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
},
{
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Raised",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1005", "type": "DeleteMe" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }
        ]
},
{
    "id": "0003",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Old Fashioned",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" }
        ]
}
]';

objArray = JSON.parse(json);

objArray.reject! {|obj|
  obj['batters']['batter'].detect {|batter|
    batter['type'] == 'DeleteMe'
  }
};

result = objArray.to_json;
```

What we do here is that we first parse the json string to an array of objects and then reject those elements which have batter of type 'DeleteMe' inside them.

Hope it helps.